# How can I return a ggplot object from a sub?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a subroutine in r, to calculate means and ranges. As a result of this, it should return a complete ggplot, which will be processed (saved or printed) in the main.

Here is the code:

```
myqcc<-function(messung, sample)
{

require(ggplot2)
y<-cbind(messung,sample)
x1<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,mean)
myrange<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,range)
stat<-cbind(x1,"range"=myrange$messung[,2]-myrange$messung[,1])
x2<-mean(stat$messung)
range1<-mean(stat$range)
A2<-0.577
D3<-0
D4<-2.115
UCLm<-x2+A2*range1
LCLm<-x2-A2*range1
UCLr<-range1*D4
LCLr<-range1*D3

g1<-ggplot(stat,aes(x=sample,y=messung)) + geom_line() +  geom_point()  + geom_hline(aes(LCLm), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") +geom_hline(aes(UCLm), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") + ggtitle("X-Bar Chart for current samples")
return(g1)      
}
ggsave(myqcc(x,y), file="Stichprobe.jpg", width=9, height=4,dpi=100)
```

Running it, results in "LCLm can not be found".

Here is the output from debug:

```
myqcc<-function(messung, sample)
+ {
+   
+   require(ggplot2)
+   y<-cbind(messung,sample)
+   x1<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,mean)
+   myrange<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,range)
+   stat<-cbind(x1,"range"=myrange$messung[,2]-myrange$messung[,1])
+   x2<-mean(stat$messung)
+   range1<-mean(stat$range)
+   A2<-0.577
+   D3<-0
+   D4<-2.115
+ 
+ UCLm<-x2+A2*range1
+ LCLm<-x2-A2*range1
+ UCLr<-range1*D4
+ LCLr<-range1*D3
+ 
+ g1<-ggplot(mystat,aes(x=sample,y=messung)) + geom_line() +    geom_point()  + geom_hline(aes(LCLm), colour="#BB0000",    linetype="dashed")    +geom_hline(aes(UCLm), colour="#BB0000",    linetype="dashed") + ggtitle("X-    Bar Chart for current samples")
+ browser()
+ return(g1)        
+ }
> ggsave(myqcc(x,y), file="Stichprobe.jpg", width=9,    height=4,dpi=100)
Called from: myqcc(x, y)
Browse[1]> LCLm
[1] 2.970867
Browse[1]> 
debug bei #22:return(g1)
Browse[2]> 
Fehler in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Objekt 'LCLm' nicht gefunden
```

As you can see, LCLm is defined and has a value, but in ggplot it can not be used.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide the dataset so your problem isn't totally paste-and-run but it wouldn't matter.  I made a  "layer specific dataset" for your geom_hline layer which does the trick.  I also added the "yintercept" tag which seems more in conforming to the [reference examples](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_hline.html).

```
myqcc<-function(messung, sample)
{

  require(ggplot2)
  y<-cbind(messung,sample)
  x1<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,mean)
  myrange<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,range)
  stat<-cbind(x1,"range"=myrange$messung[,2]-myrange$messung[,1])
  x2<-mean(stat$messung)
  range1<-mean(stat$range)
  A2<-0.577
  D3<-0
  D4<-2.115
  UCLm<-x2+A2*range1
  LCLm<-x2-A2*range1
  UCLr<-range1*D4
  LCLr<-range1*D3
  layerSpecificDataSet <- data.frame(a=UCLm,b=LCLm)
  g1<-ggplot(stat,aes(x=sample,y=messung))  + geom_line()  +  geom_point()  + 
    geom_hline(data=layerSpecificDataSet,aes(yintercept=a), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") + 
    geom_hline(data=layerSpecificDataSet,aes(yintercept=b), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") + 
    ggtitle("X-Bar Chart for current samples")

  return(g1)      
}

print(myqcc(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)))
```

Note that you can combine the two hline layers into one like this:

```
geom_hline(data=layerSpecificDataSet,aes(yintercept=c(a,b)), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed")
```

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` looks in the data frame then in the global environment for `UCLm`, but it is located in neither; it is located in the environment of the function. Adding `environment = environment()` to `ggplot()` should fix the problem. [See here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/743) for an explanation.

```
myqcc<-function(messung, sample)
{

require(ggplot2)
y<-cbind(messung,sample)
x1<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,mean)
myrange<-aggregate(messung~sample,data=y,range)
stat<-cbind(x1,"range"=myrange$messung[,2]-myrange$messung[,1])
x2<-mean(stat$messung)
range1<-mean(stat$range)
A2<-0.577
D3<-0
D4<-2.115
UCLm<-x2+A2*range1
LCLm<-x2-A2*range1
UCLr<-range1*D4
LCLr<-range1*D3

g1<-ggplot(stat,aes(x=sample,y=messung), environment = environment()) + geom_line() +  geom_point()  + geom_hline(aes(LCLm), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") +geom_hline(aes(UCLm), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed") + ggtitle("X-Bar Chart for current samples")
return(g1)      
}

myqcc(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
```